# inactiveInterval invalidation in servlet

Tags: java, session, servlets, logout

In my java EE project i'm trying to make it so, that if a user is inactive for more than 60 minutes the session will invalidate.

but i'm not sure in which servlet/jsp to put my

```
 session.setMaxInactiveInterval(3600);
        if(session.getMaxInactiveInterval() > 3600){
            session.invalidate();
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").include(request, response);
}
```

i have put it in my logout.java servlet, but i'm not sure the code will apply everywhere or do i have to put the code snippet everywhere?